# Dividing a dictionary into a list of smaller dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have extracted data from a table, but its not a regular table made with TR/TD tags but made with DIV and SPAN. I have got my data in a dictonary

```
{'ab1911': '2', 'ab1912': '1', 'ab1938': '1', 'ab1939': '0','ab1965': '18', 'ab1966': '12', 'ab1993': '18', 'ab1994': '10','ab2021': '5', 'ab2022': '21', 'ab2049': '4', 'ab2050': '4'}.
```

here the keys of the dictionary are unique ID of the element and are dynamic in nature. Every reload the ID changes.

Actual data in the web table is like this

```
Revision | Iteraion
   2          1
   1          0
   18         12
   18         10
   5          21
   4          4
```

What I have to is select the row with max Revision, if the Revision is same then the one with max Iteration. Here the right answer will be **Revision 18** and **Iteration 12**

What I am thinking is If I can convert the dictionary into a list of smaller dictionary like this

```
[{'ab1911': '2', 'ab1912': '1'},{'ab1938': '1', 'ab1939': '0'},{'ab1965': '8', 'ab1966': '18'},{'ab1993': '18', 'ab1994': '10'},{'ab2021': '5', 'ab2022': '21'},{'ab2049': '4', 'ab2050': '4'}]
```

and then compare the first key value of each element of the list and find the max value.
After getting the value, with key(its ID of selector) I can select the max value from the table. 
So how can I convert the dictionary into the list of smaller dictionary

Comment: This might be easier to solve by changing how you parse the table. Also, what do you do if you have three consecutive IDs in your dictionary?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Are the dict keys guaranteed to be ordered?

Comment: @Graipher I have a parent div tag under which all the data comes in. I have used find_Elements_by_xpath to get all the data in child tag with ID. Since the ID are dynamic but unique, using for loop, I stored the data in a dictionary with ID as key and its value. So key "ab1911" and "ab1912" are corresponding values. I am using a **if** condition to remove the values that are not needed.

Comment: @wjandrea ver 3.6.5

Comment: Don't put this in the comments, [edit] your question to include any additional information. Instead of your ASCII table, a short extract of the HTML code might make this way easier.

Comment: @Devbrath_R Are the dict keys guaranteed to be ordered?

Comment: @Devbrath_R Are you using CPython, or another implementation like PyPy? If you're not sure, you're probably using CPython.

Comment: @wjandrea i guess CPython and yes it is guaranteed to be ordered like that but that is the output of 1 value that I get from an excel. Usually the work is put the VersionNo in the web and get the latest revision and Iteration. The data in output table might have 1 row or 10 rows depending on the data provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to accomplish the task exactly as you described it with no other considerations about cleanliness or portability, the following code generates the array you want to see:

```
dict = {'ab1911': '2', 'ab1912': '1', 'ab1938': '1', 'ab1939': '0','ab1965': '18', 'ab1966': '12', 'ab1993': '18', 'ab1994': '10','ab2021': '5', 'ab2022': '21', 'ab2049': '4', 'ab2050': '4'}
arr = []
subdict = {}

itr = 0
for key,val in dict.items():
    subdict.update({key : val})
    itr = itr+1
    if(itr == 2):
        itr = 0
        arr.append(subdict)
        subdict = {}

print(arr)
```

Comment: This what I was looking for, Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution from Official Documentation

If you refer to the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) on the official documentation, there is an example of iteration by chunks of `n`. We can iterate over the keys of your original `dict` on a pairwise basis and create the `list` of `dict` you require.

#### Original Grouper Method in Itertools Recipes

```py
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

#### Modification into a Pairwise Method

```py
def pairwise(iterable, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * 2
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

#### Iterating over pairs and creating list of dicts

```py
output = []
for key_one, key_two in pairwise(source_dict.keys()):
    output.append({key_one: source_dict[key_one], key_two: source_dict[key_two]})
```

#### Sidenote

As suggested by the comments, you might want to reconsider how you are reading in your data if at all possible.

Comment: You might want to also mention that this relies on the dictionary already being in the correct order (and being ordered at all, i.e. Python 3.7+ or CPython 3.6+).